# GPS Icon in actionbar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to show an icon in the actionbar providing the signal strength of the GPS locations.
So whenever I receive a locationUpdate, I want to change the icon according to the accuracy.

I could setup an nonclickable menu item, but I can't update it on demand?

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that calling the activity's invalidateOptionsMenu() method will cause the ActionBar to be invalidated, so you can then update the icon in the onCreateOptionsMenu().